# Javascript Service worker onload show notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, push-notification, service-worker

I have a service worker that is registered, but I want to loop a function to check for updates on the server and show a notification even when tabs are closed.

With the following code in the serviceworker.js, I get an error; 
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: No active registration available on the ServiceWorkerRegistration."

```
self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: 'We have received a push message',
        icon: '',
        tag: ''
})
```

I want the notification to pop up when the browser is opens like how Facebook does it.

Comment: Where are you running that code? Is it in one of the event listeners that you have registered in the service worker?

Comment: @Marco No its not. I put it there at first, but then I don't know how to invoke those events to run automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that, I suggest you look at the examples on the Service Worker Cookbook: https://serviceworke.rs/, it will help clarify your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to understand first the lifecyle of [service-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

```
    // listen for a push notification from gcm, as only it can reiterate 
    // your push-notifications to your clients subscriber id
    // put your code inside listener

       self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
          console.log('Received a push message', event);

         // here you can make rest calls to fetch data against the subscriber-id 
         // and accordingly, set data 
         // keep in mind that your server sends push notifications to gcm
         // and then your subscribers receive them here

         var title = 'title' || 'data-from-rest-call';  
         var body = 'body' || 'data-from-rest-call';  
         var icon = '/your image path' || 'data-from-rest-call';  
         var tag = 'tag' || 'data-from-rest-call';

         // waitUntil is a callback, it triggers when the push is ready.
         event.waitUntil(  
         //here your ready notifications get triggered
         self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
           body: body,  
           icon: icon,  
           tag: tag  
         })  
      );  
    });
```

> Refer google's getting started with [web-push-notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en) for detailed understanding.